Why doesn't the Goldman Equation take into account ions that have no permeability?
While I was studying the Hodgkin-Huxley model, I encountered an a phenomena that confused me a lot.
I couldn't find the answer myself, so I wanted to ask here.
While calculating the equilibrium potential with the Goldman equation, why do we neglect the ions to which the cell wall is impermeable?
Let's say there is only sodium solution on both sides and only sodium can pass through the membrane. After the equilibrium state, if we add potassium ions to the side where the potential is high (let's say inside in this example). Outward sodium current must occur because the force resulting from the electrical force and density difference is not in balance (due to the increasing strength of the electrical force).
In the last case, the sodium density difference (and therefore the external/internal ratio) changes, but according to the Goldman equation, the voltage should not change because the added potassium cannot pass through the membrane.

No one has a bucket of potassium ions to add to solution. Whenever you have potassium ions you have some anion along with it.

The equation is for biological systems and as Bryan has pointed out, charged ions cannot be unilaterally added on either side of the membrane and ions are always accompanied by an opposite charge.
Biological fluids are neutral. So why is there polarisation of membranes?
This is because of the sodium potassium pump that consumes approximately 30% of ATP at rest! It maintains a gradient of sodium and potassium on either side(sodium being higher on the outside and potassium on the inside). But again the fluids are neutral as i mentioned. Sodium on the outside is offset by anions and so is potassium intracellularly.
Read this carefully now,
the diffusable ions form a very thin layer of charge on either side of the membrane like a capacitor. As the layer is very thin, only a few ions are required to move on either side to change the potential making the process of depolarisation and repolarisation of membranes very rapid. Resting membrane being permeable to potassium only, potassium diffuses out along its concentration gradient(establised by the Na-K pump) and quickly settles on the outside of membrane creating a positive charge on the outside and the electrostatic gradient balances the concentration gradient. Therefore at resting state membrane potential is determined only by concentration of potassium on either side of membrane. That's why we are so concerned about hypokalemia and hyperkalemia states in our body.
When sodium channels are opened due to stimulus, sodium rushes along its concentration gradient until it is offset by electrostatic force in a similar manner. As soon as the channels close, potassium again restores the original state by diffusing out.
Hope this helps, i struggled with the same doubt earlier until a friend of mine explained it to me.
